# How to create Google Chat API configuration with terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-chat-api

I would like to create a chatbot within my organization using Google Chat API as a terraform resource.

I can create it on the console but I would like to provision it as a terraform resource. I couldn't find a google chat api resource or anything similar in the hashicorp/google provider, although I'm fairly new to GCP.

Comment: Did you try asking Chat GPT?

Comment: @Mocas ChatGPT gives wrong answers to questions like this. It's one of the limitations of GPT and also a reason that StackOerflow has banned ChatGPT for providing answers. It's usually wrong.